# Why do graphing calculators plot this function wrong? Wolfram Mathematica example.

Tags: graphing-functions, math-software

[Wrong graph of the function f(x)=-1^x](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aomh8.jpg)

The function in question is $f(x)=-1^x$ and the plot example is from Wolfram Mathematica. The graph is supposed to show a zig-zag otherwise known as the triangle waveform. This problem happened on Microsoft Mathematics, Desmos online graphing calculator, another graphing calculator online, everywhere except Microsoft Excel so far.

Wolfram Language code for the graph linked is simply: Plot[-1^x, {x, -100, 100}]

Comment: Do you maybe mean to plot $(-1)^x$ instead?  Exponentiation is carried out first, and $1^x$ is uniformly equal to $1$, so $-1^x = -1$ for all values of $x$.

Comment: PEMDAS: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+(-1)%5Ex

Comment: I'm curious. Does Microsoft Excel really get this wrong?

Comment: Microsoft Excel is the only one that gets it right, but shows a triangle, not a sine.

Comment: No no, $-1^x = -(1^x) = -(1) = -1$ is right. So there should be no oscillation of any kind.

Comment: Example code from Excel: "-C2^B2 " shows oscillation, however I now tried "Plot[(-1)^x, {x, -100, 100}]" in Wolfram Mathematica and I don't get the oscillation :(

Comment: (-1)^x is not understood by desmos.com either...

Comment: How do you define $(-1)^x$ for $x$ real?

Comment: I just did the above code. Not even Microsoft Mathematics accepts the correction the correction $(-1)^x$

Comment: I think I understand now... $(-1)^x$ can produce imaginary numbers when the domain is set to all real numbers, for example $(-1)^\frac{1}{2}=\sqrt[2]{ -1^1}=\sqrt[2]{-1}=i$ ,  $(-1)^\frac{3}{2}=\sqrt[2]{(-1)^3}=\sqrt[2]{-1}=i$, etc.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote according to order of operations is $-1^x=-1$. You meant $(-1)^x$ probably. See:

http://m.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%28-1%29%5Ex&x=0&y=0

Answer (score 0):

The problem I encountered was twofold:

1) $f(x)=-1^x$, won't show oscillatory motion

because

$=-1^x=-(1^x)-(1)=-1$

2) $f(x)=(-1)^x$, won't plot

because

if $\{x|x \in \mathbb R\} \land x=a/2b$ where $b \in \mathbb N$

"$x$ is in the domain of all real numbers and $x=a/$some even number"

where

$a \neq 2b \lor a \notin \mathbb Q \lor a=2n+1$ where $n \in \mathbb N$

"the numerator $a$ is not equal to the divisor or is irrational or odd"

then

$ (-1)^x \in \mathbb C \land (-1)^x=i=\sqrt[2n]{-1}, n\in \mathbb N$

"$(-1)^x$ is in the domain of all complex numbers and equal to the even root of -1."

In layman terms, when $-(1)$ is elevated to a power other than an integer then the imaginary number $i$ (which is not plottable over a range of real numbers) tend to appear over the range of $(-1)^x$.

The solution:

$f(x)=(-1)^x$, will plot if $\{x|x\in \mathbb Z\}$

"$x$ is in the domain of all integers"

Sample MATLAB code:

x=-100:1:100; %Domain in increments of 1 plots the set of all integers

y=(-1)^.x;

plot(x,y)

The result is the graph of a triangle waveform or "zig-zag."

A new problem arised in Wolfram Mathematica for me. The plot function Plot[] is in the format Plot[expression,{var,varmin,varmax}] with no option for setting the increment of the domain to any desired value. In the case of $(-1)^x$ to 1. Any help with this?

Comment: If you want a triangle wave, you could use $(-1)^{\text{floor}(x)}(2x-2\text{floor}(x)-1)$.